# How to download a CSV for all links in google's index?

Tags: seo, google-search

If a website is indexed in Google, what is the best way to find all the indexed URLs of the website. Any recommended tool would be better for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

open webmaster tool 
click 
search traffic->choose links to your site-> it appears who links the most tab in left side and click more options 
Now appears more accepted backlinks appear 
Now to see Top in right corner down latest link button appears
if you click this button downloading csv format links.

if you want to check indexed pages in google
please follow the step
in google search bar you just type site:yoursite.com

Thanks,
Anandhan.P